# Swiftsupport folder adding extra size to binary

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6.1

My xcode project contains objective c and swift code. Also, EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT is set to NO. But when I prepare binary out of it, it creates 2 folders. One is normal Payload and other one SwiftSupport which contains set of duplicate frameworks which are present at Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks. Please help me out to understand why swiftsupport folder is getting added. Is this the reason for big .ipa file?